# AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'http_backend' when starting shinken-arbiter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, pip, nagios

[Shinken](http://www.shinken-monitoring.org/) is installed via `pip` in a `virtualenv`:

```
sudo /opt/shinken/bin/pip install -e git+https://github.com/naparuba/shinken.git#egg=shinken
```

Everything goes smoothly until the last step:

```
sudo /opt/shinken/bin/shinken-arbiter -d -c /opt/shinken/etc/nagios.cfg -c /opt/shinken/etc/shinken-specific.cfg

[1385534688] Critical : I got an unrecoverable error. I have to exit
[1385534688] Critical : You can log a bug ticket at https://github.com/naparuba/shinken/issues/new to get help
[1385534688] Critical : Exception trace follows: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/shinken/src/shinken/shinken/daemons/arbiterdaemon.py", line 563, in main
    self.load_config_file()
  File "/opt/shinken/src/shinken/shinken/daemons/arbiterdaemon.py", line 467, in load_config_file
    self.http_backend = self.conf.http_backend
AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'http_backend'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/shinken/bin/shinken-arbiter", line 8, in <module>
    execfile(__file__)
  File "/opt/shinken/src/shinken/bin/shinken-arbiter", line 118, in <module>
    daemon.main()
  File "/opt/shinken/src/shinken/shinken/daemons/arbiterdaemon.py", line 563, in main
    self.load_config_file()
  File "/opt/shinken/src/shinken/shinken/daemons/arbiterdaemon.py", line 467, in load_config_file
    self.http_backend = self.conf.http_backend
AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'http_backend'
```

`arbiterdaemon.py`: https://github.com/naparuba/shinken/blob/master/shinken/daemons/arbiterdaemon.py

- Python 2.7.6
- pip 1.4.1 from /opt/shinken/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
- shinken-arbiter: 1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `http_backend` property is missing in the master branch. I have tried to reinstall the branch 1.4 and now it's working fine:

```
sudo /opt/shinken/bin/pip install -e git+https://github.com/naparuba/shinken.git@branch-1.4#egg=shinken
```